# Ionic and FB.AppEvents.activateApp(); issues

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm failing to implement a Facebook app install campaign. My ionic app initiated the FB JS SDK as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs). In my app init code I include the following:

```
FB.AppEvents.activateApp();
```

When I do, I get the following error:

> You can only use this function in Facebook Canvas environment

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue here, did you find out a solution?

Comment: @peeol - In the official facebook for developers link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent, its mentioned as "Note: App Launches and App Installs are now logged automatically. It's no longer necessary to call activateApp to log those events." So looks like this call may not be necessary. Please update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question. I managed to have it working and leverage the Facebook analytics too by including the following Cordova plugin:

cordova-plugin-facebook4
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Once I included the plugin, I did not need to manually call the activate app event.
Moreover, the latest Facebook documentation mentions that this call is no longer needed.

Comment: You may have to check out this as well - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent. Especially the note as mentioned in my comments above, its not longer required even if you dont use plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In the official facebook for developers [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent), its mentioned as

> "Note: App Launches and App Installs are now logged automatically. It's no longer necessary to call activateApp to log those events."

So looks like this call may not be necessary at all.